# Sending a message 2 hours after the last message discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I can't figure out how to make my discord bot send a message 2 hours after the last message. The problem for me is that I want the bot to reset the 2 hours timer if a new message comes, but I don't know how to do that without breaking the program. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you provide us with the code for your bot?

Comment: Which part of the code should i add? I don't think it's worth loading 300 lines of code in here. Mostly what it does is it handles user messages with @client.event async def on_message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To point you in a general direction. You want something like

```
await asyncio.sleep(60*60*2)
do_stuff
```

One way would be to take the above lines in a function and run them as a task in asyncio and you somewhere store it as a persitent variable.
If the command arrives you take the old task, cancel it, start a new one.

```py
async def nested():
    await asyncio.sleep(60*60*20)
    return 42

async def schedule():
    # Schedule nested() to run soon concurrently
    # with "main()".
    bot.mytask = asyncio.create_task(nested())

    # "task" can now be used to cancel "nested()", or
    # can simply be awaited to wait until it is complete:
    await bot.mytask

async def cancelit():
    bot.mytask.cancel()
    # reshedule it...
```

Comment: It seems to be what i need, but bot.mytask.cancel() gives out "unresolved reference" in cancelit function. How do i make this task visible outside of the schedule function?

Comment: What I did not add was a precheck if bot.mytask actually is set.
Can you post the whole error.
To make it visible i suggested bot but maybe something else a global variable, dictionary is better. Discord classes have sometimes extra gimmicks that make them unintuitive from native python.